# Получить полный путь

Tags: php, сервер

Как получить путь к странице с которой сделан переход,
типа `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`
только нужен именно путь без http://... путь к странице (файлу)
типа c:/server/..../file.txt.
все на одном сервере (сайте)

Comment: На чистом PHP только `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, но он очень не надёжный. Такие фреймворки как Yii2 сохраняют данные о предыдущей странице. Если вы используете чистый PHP - сохраняйте данные о предыдущей странице сами. К примеру можно в $_SSESION записывать.

Answer (score 0):

[http](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) протокол не устанавливает соответсвие url и файла на сервере, поэтому никак

Если понадобилось сделать это, то у вас должен быть класс(функция) который знает соответствие url и пути к файлу

Вообще обсалютно любому [http](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) запросу верить нельзя, так как вы предыдущий url не можете проверить - задача превращается в невыполнимую